# Use MySQL to wrap another DBMS via ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc, sybase, filemaker, advantage-database-server

I need to connect two different solutions together solution A is in Sybase (ADS) and solution B is in Filemaker. Since Filemaker is only able to have a live connection to Oracle, MS Server and MySQL via ODBC.

I thought about creating a middleware between FileMaker and Sybase using MySQL. I search google and haven't found anything except for full migration.

So question is via MySQL is it possible to query a second DBMS via ODBC? So I can make the tables of solution B visible to A.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has something called "Linked Server Provider". Linked Server could be an ODBC source. May be you can use it to dynamically link from FileMaker to Sybase. You can also use SQL Server Express, which is FileMaker ESS compatible.